# How to set radio button status with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

What method would be best to use to selectively set a single or multiple radio button(s) to a desired setting with JavaScript?

Comment: @RintoGeorge, Could you please tell us why?

Comment: @Starx - jQuery took care of my most recent rash; surely it can check radio buttons!

Comment: @RintoGeorge, I agree, i love jQuery too, but this is too simple. We dont need jQuery for this.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Very simple

```
radiobtn = document.getElementById("theid");
radiobtn.checked = true;
```

Comment: Sweet - nice and easy thankyou. If I was to try to modify a nuber of radio buttons with sequential id's radio1, radio2 etc, then it might be ...... function check_radio() {
  for (var i = 1, radiobtn; radiobtn = document.getElementById("radio" + i); ++i)
    radiobtn.checked = true;
}

Comment: I think `radiobtn.checked` should receive `'checked'` instead of `true`, although i can't remember where i read this.

Comment: @RafaelBarros, you're confusing the Javascript-property `.checked` with the xhtml-attribute `checked="checked"`. Since xhtml tried to be xml-compliant, no attributes without value were allowed (in contrast to html 4 or 5 where `<sometag checked>` is correct syntax). Regardless of which mark-up language you're using, Javascript is Javascript and in Javascript objects have properties which could very well be a boolean value. Indeed, the DOM object associated with `<input type="radio" />` has a property `.checked` which can be `true` or `false`.

Comment: I suggest to add `var` before `radiobtn = ...` to avoid having it in the global scope.

Comment: If you're using another button to activate it, it's even simpler: just include `onclick="theid.checked=true"` in the input tag of the activating button.

Answer (score 48):

the form

```
<form name="teenageMutant">
  <input value="aa" type="radio" name="ninjaTurtles"/>
  <input value="bb" type="radio" name="ninjaTurtles"/>
  <input value="cc" type="radio" name="ninjaTurtles" checked/>
</form>
```

value="cc" will be checked by default, if you remove the "checked" non of the boxes will be checked when the form is first loaded.

```
document.teenageMutant.ninjaTurtles[0].checked=true;
```

now value="aa" is checked. The other radio check boxes are unchecked.

see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/yaArr/

You may do the same using the form id and the radio button id. Here is a form with id's.

```
<form id="lizardPeople" name="teenageMutant">
  <input id="dinosaurs" value="aa" type="radio" name="ninjaTurtles"/>
  <input id="elephant" value="bb" type="radio" name="ninjaTurtles"/>
  <input id="dodoBird" value="cc" type="radio" name="ninjaTurtles" checked/>
</form>
```

value="cc" is checked by default.

```
document.forms["lizardPeople"]["dinosaurs"].checked=true;
```

now value="aa" with id="dinosaurs" is checked, just like before.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jPfXS/

Answer (score 22):

You can also explicitly set value of radio button:

```
<form name="gendersForm">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" /> Man
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" /> Woman
</form>
```

with the following script:

```
document.gendersForm.gender.value="F";
```

and corresponding radio button will be checked automatically.

Look at the [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbrbot/dbswj90m/).

Comment: Works perfect until you try it in IE <.<

Answer (score 20):

Vanilla Javascript:

```
yourRadioButton.checked = true;
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[name=foo]').prop('checked', true);
```

or

```
$("input:checkbox").val() == "true"
```

Comment: Thanks - yes I had checked and found a number of different methods. Unfortunatley after a trying a few I was not having much success. Appreciate your time

Comment: @vinomarky - The thought crossed my mind, but I didn't want to come across as a bully.  I don't actually care that much if a question is posted here that can be found elsewhere.

Comment: @vinomarky : i still not get why u delete my post as ur qus posted get negative point.

Comment: @Deepakmahajan: Sorry, have no idea of what you refer to. I have never deleted anyones posts, in fact I dont even think I have priviledge to do so even if I wanted to

Comment: Your Vanilla Javascript `yourRadioButton.checked` looks tempting but is not recommended in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

Comment: It's actually funny, because I am sure I've used that 2nd jQuery method with `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. after the `$(...)` part of it to do this before, but when I just tried `$('input[name=foo]')[0].attr('checked', true);` I got `Object doesn't support this property or method`.  Same thing if I put `('checked', 'checked')`. But when I mixed the JavaScript with the jQuery option and did `$('input[name=foo]')[0].checked = true;` it set just fine.  Odd.

Comment: You should be using `prop()` instead of `attr()` for setting boolean values.

Answer (score 11):

```
/**
 * setCheckedValueOfRadioButtonGroup
 * @param {html input type=radio} vRadioObj 
 * @param {the radiobutton with this value will be checked} vValue 
 */
function setCheckedValueOfRadioButtonGroup(vRadioObj, vValue) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName(vRadioObj.name);
    for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
        if (radios[j].value == vValue) {
            radios[j].checked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```js
myRadio.checked=true
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="myRadio">My radio<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am configuring a radio button within a document fragment and tried using `radiobtn.checked = true;`.

That didn't work so I instead went with this solution:

```
radiobtn.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: You can also use `radiobtn.setAttribute("checked", "");` to select it.

Comment: This is what works if you are using Stimulus in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#id_of_radiobutton").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: This is jQuery, not JavaScript, innit?

Answer (score 0):

This sets checked using name to cycle through the elements and a value check to set the desired element to true. I kept it as simple as possible, its pretty easy to put it into a function or a loop, etc.

variable 'nameValue' is the radio elements name value

variable 'value' when matched sets the radio button

```
Array.from(  document.querySelectorAll('[name="' + nameValue + '"]')   ).forEach((element,index) =>
                {
                    if (value === element.value) {
                        element.checked = true;
                    } else {
                        element.checked = false;
                    }
                });
```