# Alternative for .checkboxradio("refresh") so that I will not have to use JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have radio buttons, where the checked option changes. In order to show this change to the front-end I have to use `$('input[name='+name+']').checkboxradio("refresh");`. Is there any other way in Javascript or jQuery to refresh the options?

I don't want to use JQM just for this, for my whole web app.

Comment: The checked prop changes programmatically, that is why the radio buttons need to be refreshed.

Comment: `checkboxradio` is a widget from JQM, so if you don't want to call the methods provided by the widget, then don*t use the widget = use a normal radio button (without JQM). If you want the nice looking radio buttons of JQM, then you will also have to live with calling `refresh` imo

Comment: If I use normal buttons without data-role=button etc but just by using input type=button which is a normal button, is not the problem. The problem is even when I will use the normal input type=radio button withou JQM, how I will show in the front-end the change of the checked radio buttons that is made programmatically.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476617/how-to-set-radio-button-status-with-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476617/how-to-set-radio-button-status-with-javascript)