# Setting "Checked" in Radio Button using JQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have this `javascript` function to set `radio` button to `checked` state with in `php`

I call this `javascript` function using `php` **echo**

I tried placing `javascript` everywhere but still `php` doesn't set the radio button `checked`

This is my `php` with `javascript`

```
                     <div class="row text-center">
                             <script type="text/javascript">

                                function checkRadio(serviceid) {
                                   $('#radio' + serviceid).prop('checked', true);
                                 }
                                </script>

                              <?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>checkRadio({$row['serviceid']});</script>"; ?>

                             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 ad-image">
                             <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" value="1" class="input-hidden" />
                             <label for="radio1">
                                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/70" alt="I'm radio" />
                            </label>
                        </div>

                      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 ad-image">
                        <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" value="2" class="input-hidden" />
                           <label for="radio2">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/70" alt="I'm radio" />
                            </label>
                        </div>
          </div>
```

`$row['serviceid']` which is in a `while loop` (which  runs only one time) and it carries values 1 (e.i `$row['serviceid'] = 1`)

**I tried placing `alert(serviceid)` and it works fine.**

But it doesn't set `radio1` to set state

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Original answer can be found here: [How to set radio button status with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476617/how-to-set-radio-button-status-with-javascript)

If you just want to set radio button status to checked you really don't need jQuery, you can simply use vanilla javascript:

```
    function checkRadio(serviceid) {
        radiobtn = document.getElementById("radio" + serviceid);
        radiobtn.checked = true;
    }
```