# Hyperlink to and display a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used this CodePen to create Tabs on my webpage: `https://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/tfjFl/`

I want to be able to provide a user with a hyperlink which takes them to the specific tab and displays the content. E.g www.example.com#tab2

I have tried using Anchor tags, and the user is taken to the correct place on the page, but the tab is not displayed. What do i need to do in order to instruct the tabs to display?  I assume i will need Jquery, but im not sure where to start.

Here is the codepen code:

```
   <main>

  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Codepen</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Dribbble</label>

  <section id="content1">
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content2">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin.
    </p>

  </section>


</main>

    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

*,*::before,*::after{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100vh;}body{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;padding:40px;font:14px/1.5 'Open Sans',sans-serif;color:#345;background:#f0f2f4;}

p:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

main {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #abc;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #abc;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }
label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }
label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16c'; }
label[for*='4']:before { content: '\f171'; }

label:hover {
  color: #789;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #0af;
  border: 1px solid #abc;
  border-top: 2px solid #0af;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  label {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

*,*::before,*::after{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100vh;}body{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;padding:40px;font:14px/1.5 'Open Sans',sans-serif;color:#345;background:#f0f2f4;}

p:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

main {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #abc;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #abc;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }
label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }
label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16c'; }
label[for*='4']:before { content: '\f171'; }

label:hover {
  color: #789;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #0af;
  border: 1px solid #abc;
  border-top: 2px solid #0af;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  label {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>

  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Codepen</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Dribbble</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Stack Overflow</label>

  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Bitbucket</label>

  <section id="content1">
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content2">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content3">
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content4">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: You don't need Javascript. You can use pseudo-class ```:target``` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Comment: @weroro - thanks for your reply. I didnt know about this before. I have found some example of it working. But i'm not sure how i can change the example i'm using. I've tried changing parts of the CSS but i keep breaking it. Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need javascript for this. You'll need the javascript to [get the hash from your url](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp), and then using this information to [check the input radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476617/how-to-set-radio-button-status-with-javascript) with the ID that was on the hash.

Hope this helps you to move on.