# how to show checkbox as checked in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NdjK.jpg)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.editbtn').on('click', function(){

            $('#editmodal').modal('show');
            $tr=$(this).closest('tr');
            var data= $tr.children("td").map(function(){
              return $(this).text();
            }).get();
            console.log(data);

            $('#update_id').val(data[0]);
            $('#finame').val(data[1]);
            $('#liname').val(data[2]);
            $('#Eimail').val(data[3]);
            $('#ContactNumber').val(data[4]);
            $('#Giender').val(data[5]);
            $('#Dob').val(data[6]);
            $('#addriess').val(data[7]);
            $('#Ciity').val(data[8]);
            $('#pinicode').val(data[9]);
            $('#stiate').val(data[10]);
            $('#countiry').val(data[11]);
            $('#HobbyiDrawing').each(function(){ this.checked = true; });
            $('#HobbyiDrawing').each(function(){ this.checked = false; });
           // $('#HobbyiDrawing').attr('checked', true);
            $('#HighiSchool').val(data[13]);
        });
});
```

i want to checkbox and radio button as checked in update modal form how to resolve it please guide me

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#HobbyiDrawing').attr("checked",true);
```

You can do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

try checked attribute in both input tags as give down

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red" checked>

<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this construction for check all checkbox via JQuery

```
onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').prop('checked', this.checked);"
```

For radio buttons you can use those methods - [How to set radio button status with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476617/how-to-set-radio-button-status-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

- Set your dynamic value in values variable to checked checkbox or
  radio

```js
$('input[value='+values+'').attr('checked', true);
```